# How to instantiate inherited class using base constructor?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor

I'm starting to believe this isn't possible, but I want to see if may be there is something else that I'm overlooking that can help me with this.

With this setup:

```
public abstract class parent
{
    protected int x;

    public parent(int i)
    {
        x = i;
    }
}

public class child : parent { }
```

Do I have the ability to do this:

```
child c = new child(2);
```

Which is instantiating the child class using the base constructor?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to avoid having to implement the same constructor for all derived classes, when they all actually do the same thing, which is initializing a value to the inherited member.

I also want to avoid having to write this in each child implementation:

```
public child(int i) : base(i) { }
```

So, how can I make constructors inheritable?  If not possible, what do I do to simulate this?

Comment: no you cant do like that

Comment: No you can't if you would try that compiler will report error there stating something like "no overload default constructor found in the base class"!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid writing that?  If it's purely because you don't want to have to type it out, invest in something like Resharper - it will write it for you in a couple of keystrokes.

Comment: I don't think you can if you don't want to avoid the chile implementation.

Comment: That won't work; it would mean every single class has a parameterless constructor, derived from `System.Object`.

Comment: Since x is public, you can just create c = new child { x = 2 }; . But yeah what you are asking won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses.

From the comments and my further research into this, I have learned that **constructors are not inheritable** for many reasons. One of them is that inheriting constructors is a specific case, which could lead to inheriting unwanted constructors all the way up the hierarchy to class `object`; that would also require extra code to hide those unwanted constructors. So **either way, extra code exists** -- this is an answer I was looking for.

A workaround I was looking for is to create a method such as `SetX(int i)` which can be called after calling the parameterless constructor. However, that leads to even more extra code, since now any code that instantiates has to also call `SetX()`.

So, for me, an ultimate answer is to just admit and accept the inevitable, which is that you have to write this for every child class:

```
public child(int i) : base(i) { }
```

Now I can write this code with confidence.
In case you're wondering, it's not about saving one line of code, it's about setting up standards for writing goodcode and avoid unneeded lines of code all over the place.

Comment: I'd argue that "good code" isn't about the fewest lines. I mean, yes, reducing fluff and being concise with few lines of code is good. But that should all server the goal of being readable and concise. `public child(int i) : base(i) { }` is going to be instantly readable and understandable by any programmer. I guarantee any other way you might have found to do this would have been less so.

Answer (score 1):

Make your variable `x` in parent to `public`;
So use below code:

```
child c = new child();
c.x = 2;
```

I mean that you can change your way and like above code; And don't make constructors as you want.

Comment: While that is a good workaround, I meant for `x` to be `protected`. I appreciate your answer; please keep it for future people to think outside the box. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the factory pattern and override the factory method in your child-classes instead of using the constructor directly.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to avoid the "boilerplate" of `public child(int x) : base(x) { }`, but the reality is at some point you have to actually write you some code.

What you want is impossible for a couple really good reasons. The first is that children don't implicitly inherit the parent constructor. There's a good reason for that - otherwise all objects would inherit the paramaterless constructor of `Object`.

Additionally, you can't even call a Public constructor on an abstract class (there's really not much point to them).